# Item.ToString returns text listviewitem: {value} instead of just text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am using the following code to return the value of the selected item in a listbox

```
    For Each Item As Object In RTF_Macros.SelectedItems
        strSelectedMacro = (Item.ToString)
    Next
MsgBox(strSelectedMacro)
```

however the value returned is listviewitem: {XXX} not just XXX

i realize i can pull the string apart in code and just get XXX from listviewitem: {XXX} but is there a way just to get the XXX value in the first place

[image: Selected Item Result]

Comment: Firstly, please don't include tags in the title and the question. The title and the question are for the title and the question.  Tags are for tags.

Comment: As for your question, if what you actually want is the value of the `Text` property of the item then why are you calling `ToString` at all instead of getting the value of the `Text` property of the item? Every member works the way it works, not the way you want it to work.

Comment: sorry for the tag in the title just trying to be very clear in what i wanted it for. As for why i was using to string everywhere i was looking said to use this. I am still learning. I am only self taught ATM and looking to fix this moving forward.
The .TEXT option has resolved this thanks for your time

Comment: Searching the web is obviously a useful tool but you should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation.  If you're using a `ListViewItem` and you want to know how it works, ignoring the Microsoft manual page on how it works is obviously counter-productive. Depending on circumstances, you won't always find what you need or understand what you find but that's not a reason not to look. The more you use the documentation, the better you get at using it and the more of your own problems you'll be able to solve on your own.